# d3 binding to wrong component instance react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a d3 sample I'm trying to integrate with react. The component should take an array of arrays as data points (x is date and y is a float value) and render a line chart. Component is as follows:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import * as d3 from "d3";

export default class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.buildLineChart(this.props.stock.dataset.data)
  }

  buildLineChart(data){
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
              margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
              width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
              height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
              g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var data = data.map(function(d){
      return [parseTime(d[0]), +d[1]]
    });

    var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d){
        return x(d[0])
      })
      .y(function(d){
        return y(d[1]) 
      });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d[1]; }));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .select(".domain")
        .remove();

    g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 50)
        .attr("dy", "0.6em")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end");
        // .text("Price ($)");

    g.append("path")
        .datum(data)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 3)
        .attr("d", line);

  }

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8',
      borderStyle: 'solid',
      borderWidth: 'thin',
      borderRadius: '15px',
      marginLeft: '10px',
      marginRight: '10px'
    };

    return(
      <div className="form-group row col-sm-12" style={divStyle}>
          <div className="row" id="lineChartContainer">
            <svg width="768" height="300"></svg>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I have a default component that loads and everything looks fine. However when I spawn additional component instances, while additional components render, d3 writes the new line chart over the top of the old. What I get is a situation like this:
[image]

Facebook is the default component and loads fine, but when I try and spin up a Netflix component, the instance is generated, but the NFLX chart is written over top of the Facebook chart. Is there a straightforward convention to get d3 to bind to it's own component instance?

Comment: Well, I never used react and thus I'm probably wrong here, but just FYI in pure JS this line: `var svg = d3.select("svg")` tells d3 to select the **first** SVG it finds on the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the "svg" element inside the component as below,

```
buildLineChart(data){
    var svg = d3.select(this.getDOMNode()).select("svg"),
    ....
}
```

Comment: I must be on a version of React where getDOMNode is deprecated, as I got an error indicating it was not a function. However findDOMNode(this) instead of this.getDOMNode() worked, so this answer pointed me to the problem.